# HTML5 Blending modes - layers in paint program

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm creating html5 paint application and I'm currently working on blending layers. I'm wondering which of the approaches would be the best (fastest and gimp/photoshop like) to build in such program. My layers (canvases) are stacked.

1. Changing blend mode by CSS3 property (probably very fast - blending directly on graphics card)
2. Having hidden canvases (layers) and one canvas to show flattened image to user. So we draws on these hidden canvases and there is some mechanism which taking each of hidden canvas and draw it to user viewable canvas (probably slower but each context.drawImage(...) is optimized and computed on graphics card)
3. Hidden canvases (layers) are truly virtual. There is no hidden canvases elements at all. Instead there is some structure in memory which imitate canvas. These structure just saving user actions performed on this virtual layer. Then when repainting is required, user canvas is reconstructed by taking each operations from each virtual layers and paint it (true paint). Operations must be correctly ordered is such virtual layer structure (this is probably slow but may be faster than 2nd approach(we don't wasting time to draw anything on layer, just storing options how we will draw on real layer)?)
4. Blending by WebGL(probably fast)
5. Compute manually each pixel and show score to user (super slow?)

I'm using second approach but i'm not really sure it's the best (especially for more layers). I was wondering do you know any other approach, maybe you would suggest what would be better to implement blending operations to make it work as in Gimp/Adobe Photoshop

Comment: If you're talking about irreversible blending, then you can sequentially apply as many blends as you want on a single canvas. If you're talking about reversible (changeable) blending layers then that complexity is beyond the scope of a Stackoverflow Q&A.

Comment: It's a little pitty. I implemented reversible blending layers so I could answer my own question to help how to do that.

Comment: Nice! If you've already done the work, then please consider posting an answer to your own question as a benefit to the community. :-)

Comment: @markE, yup. I posted my solution, Hope will be usefull for someone :)

Answer (score 0):

My way to implement this was to have multiple canvases, each of them store it's own blending mode. But it's just virual canvas (not drawable for user). Then there is 33 times per second timer (made by RequestAnimationFrame) which grab all this canvases, flatten them and draw it to viewport. For each layer I perform blend mode change on viewport canvas. It works perfect since drawImage(...) is computed on GPU and it's really fast.

I think code is fairly easy to understand and to apply in own solutions:

```
   Process(lm: dl.LayerManager) {
        var canvasViewPort = lm.GetWorkspaceViewPort();
        var virtualLayers = lm.GetAllNonTemporary();

        canvasViewPort.Save();
        canvasViewPort.Clear();
        canvasViewPort.SetBlendMode(virtualLayers[0].GetBlendMode());
        canvasViewPort.ApplyBlendMode();
        canvasViewPort.DrawImage(virtualLayers[0], 0, 0, canvasViewPort.Width(), canvasViewPort.Height(), 0, 0, canvasViewPort.Width(), canvasViewPort.Height());
        for (var i = 1; i < virtualLayers.length; ++i) {
            var layer = virtualLayers[i];
            var shift = other.GetShift();
            canvasViewPort.SetBlendMode(virtualLayers[i].GetBlendMode());
            canvasViewPort.ApplyBlendMode();
            canvasViewPort.DrawImage(layer, 0, 0, layer.Width(), layer.Height(), shift.x, shift.y, layer.Width(), layer.Height());
        }
        canvasViewPort.Restore();
    }
```

Don't be affraid of this code. It maintains underlaying canvas, pure CanvasRenderingContext2D.

I will perform such optimization: I Won't redraw canvasViewPort until something changes on any virtual canvas.

Next optimization I would perform: Get selected layer, cache all before and all after current layer.

So it will looks like:

CurrentLayer: 3 (which might be affected by some tool)

```
[1]:L1
[2]:L2
[3]:L3
[4]:L4
[5]:L5
[6]:L6
```

Draw to temporary with appropiate blend mode [1, 2] to tmp1 and [4, 5, 6] to tmp2. 
When something change on third layer, I just need to redraw tmp1 + [3] + tmp2.
So it's just only 2 iteration's. Super fast.